# Custom formula for databars in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, conditional-formatting

How would one go about using a custom formula to determine the format conditions for databars?

Meaning, in Excel under "Conditional Formatting" there's a format called "Data Bars". However, you cannot specify the criteria that you want these bars to display for.

The scenario is that I have a range of data, and some of these values are irrelevant either due to their categorization, or being labeled as outliers. They are abnormally large and I would like for them to be excluded from the databar visualization as the bars are greatly skewed due to the large values.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PGR1.png]

Comment: This probably should be moved to stack overflow. I don't think there's a solution without using VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I have found is to utilize VBA and conditionally-select the range first, then apply the formatting to that range. VoG's solution [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/400449-conditional-range-selection-visual-basic-applications.html#post1987976) helped.

```
Sub formatDataBarRange()

    ' Build range only for cells labeled to be included
    Dim LR As Long, i As Long, r As Range
    LR = Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        If Range("B" & i).Value = "include" Then
            If r Is Nothing Then
                Set r = Range("A" & i)
            Else
                Set r = Union(r, Range("A" & i))
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    ' Add data bar formatting
    r.FormatConditions.AddDatabar
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).ShowValue = True
    r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With r.FormatConditions(1)
        .MinPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMin
        .MaxPoint.Modify newtype:=xlConditionValueAutomaticMax
    End With
    With r.FormatConditions(1).BarColor
        .Color = 2668287
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    r.FormatConditions(1).BarFillType = xlDataBarFillSolid
    r.FormatConditions(1).Direction = xlContext
    r.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.ColorType = xlDataBarColor
    r.FormatConditions(1).BarBorder.Type = xlDataBarBorderNone
    r.FormatConditions(1).AxisPosition = xlDataBarAxisAutomatic
    With r.FormatConditions(1).AxisColor
        .Color = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With r.FormatConditions(1).NegativeBarFormat.Color
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Maximum Value for the Data Bars. Anything above the maximum will simply take up the whole bar instead of skewing your results wildly like your example.

In this example I have the maximum set to 100:

[image: non-skewed data bars!]

You can set this by going to `Conditional Formatting... > Manage Rules... > Edit Rules...` and change the Maximum type to `Number`.

[image: data bars formatting]

Set this to something sane, and your skew issue should disappear.